# "[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data" when trying to get JSON data with AJAX / jQuery request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am getting the error "[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data" when trying to get JSON data with AJAX / jQuery request.

I have an index.html file which loads jQuery and tries to get data from an ajax.php file.

CONTENT of index.html

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'ajax.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : data,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (result) {
       alert(result['ajax']);
    },
    error : function () {
        alert("error");
    }
    });
```

CONTENT of ajax.php

```
$someVariable = array(
    'ajax' => 'Hello world!'
    );
echo json_encode($someVariable);
```

Accessing ajax.php through the browser displays the data correctly:

```
{"ajax":"Hello world!"}
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: console.log the data you are sending to the php file. Perhaps you didn't define it.

Comment: You were right. It wasn't defined. I think I don't need the data setting, so I have deleted it. The request now works but returns "error".

Comment: In that case you have to debug the ajax error. You will find plenty of source that can teach you how to do this.

Comment: if you're just _get_ ting data from the php script, perhaps consider using `type:'GET'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know which error you are  refering to, but I'm guessing you are enable to read the response of your json response in the success callback, if thats the case you will need to modify the response headers

```
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added that header and removed a comment section that I had in the PHP file, below the echo statement; and now the result is not error, but undefined.

Comment: I had a typo on a variable name, but still it wasn't working until I added the header you specified, so thanks for pointing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `data` variable
If you not post any data try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'ajax.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (result) {
       alert(result['ajax']);
    },
    error : function () {
        alert("error");
    }
    });
```

Comment: `POST` is designed to send data up to the server and get a response. If the intention is just to **get** data, `type` should be set to `GET` :)

Comment: I have tried with no data setting, as suggested by Wojtek B, and with GET instead of POST. Still "error" alert shows up. Will need to debug AJAX request.